# cvs checkin: Identifying the names of the files checked in

Tags: cvs, cvsnt

The [cvsnt manual](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/commit-files.html#syntax) provides a detailed list of parameters than can be passed to the postcommand module, but none of them specify the file name.

Is anybody aware of an option not listed here that would provide the name of the file being checked in?

ColinYounger - The %c command is just the command, e.g. "Commit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (thanks to an answer to a different question by [Sally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86515/does-anyone-know-the-cvs-command-line-options-to-get-the-details-of-the-last-ch#213003)) is to not use the postcommand file, but use the [loginfo file](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_18.html#SEC186) and provide the arguments ‘%{s}’

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the %c parameter pass in the command issued (including the files being committed)?